# textFieldShouldBeginEditing checking if the parameter is a specific component

Tags: storyboard, uitextfield

in textFieldShouldBeginEditing I'm checking which UITextField was triggered like so:

```
if(textField == self.nameText)
{
    textField.keyboardType = UIKeyboardTypeDefault;
}

else
{
    textField.keyboardType = UIKeyboardTypeNumberPad;
}
```

the if statement is true even when it's not the nameText textfield, I've checked in the story board if by mistake i've attached multiple UITextFields to this property and I didn't so I'm not sure why this is happening or what should I check for

suggestions are welcome

Comment: Please put `NSLog(@"%p, %p - %p", self, textField, self.nameText);` before the if and run your code again for some of your textFields. Then post the result. What you see should definitely not happen.

Comment: @MatthiasBauch did that all return addresses and here is the strange part, inside the if I'm checking the pointer of textfield and self.nameText they have different address & different value.... I've deleted the code cleaned the project then run it without the if else code, re-written the code and it works fine...VOODO in action

Answer (score 2):

Its better to use tag property to compare.
**You can set tag value in viewDidLoad**

```
e.g. self.nameText.tag = 22;
```

**OR Visually like**

[image: Tag value can be assigned visually]

```
if(textField.tag == self.nameText.tag)
{
   textField.keyboardType = UIKeyboardTypeDefault;
}
else
{
   textField.keyboardType = UIKeyboardTypeNumberPad;
}
```

Comment: Tag is a property you must enter a value into in order to compare that doesn't seem the proper way to compare

Comment: @liva - I have posted new answer as per your need

Comment: And why exactly should this be better?

Comment: @MatthiasBauch - You can change keyboard style at specific textfields and if you tag it then you can reference it anywhere in your code make some changes to it.

Comment: your previous answer was as good as this one, I just disagree with it. It's not that i didn't know where & how to assign the tag, and your solution will work, but it's not the best practice and it open future bugs when one forgets to assign a tag,delete it or gives two or more fields the same value...all these scenarios cause that a bunch of fields return true to the if.